# Ошибка при конвертации строки в дату C#

Tags: c#, datetime

При конвертации строки в дату возникает ошибка:
System.FormatException: "Строка не распознана как действительное значение DateTime."

```
string date_string = check_array[i].ToString().Split(',')[1]; // приходит "01.03.2021"

DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date_string, "dd.MM.yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

В отладчике смотрел - действительно, приходит string "01.03.2021".

Если же в коде указать конкретную дату "01.03.2021", то работает без ошибок:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("01.03.2021", "dd.MM.yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Помогите решить проблему. Спасибо.

Специально, для тех, кто не верит - принтскрин отладчика:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `В отладчике смотрел - действительно, приходит string "01.03.2021".` - прям действительно действительно? Без лишних пробелов и других символов? Подумайте сами логически, если указав вручную - работает, а через получения даты извне - нет, то явно проблема в той дате, что вы получаете.

Comment: А вы сравните `date_string` с `"01.03.2021"`, вдруг там невидимые символы затесались?

Comment: Добавил картинку отладчика

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо за наводку.
Действительно, сравнил длины строк - разные!
Оказывается, в приходящей строке были непечатные символы.
Строка приходит из javascript, поэтому это и происходит.
Решил проблему удалением указанных символов из строки перед конвертацией в дату:

```
date_string = Regex.Replace(date_string, @"\u200e", string.Empty);
```

Всем спасибо за внимание.

Comment: А так не сработает `date_string = date_string.Trim('\u200e')`? Попроще, чем регулярку дергать. И кстати, данный символ [вот что значит](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm)

Comment: Не сработает, т.к. символы '\u200e' встречаются не только по краям строки

Comment: `date_string = date_string.Replace("\u200e", string.Empty)`

Comment: c Regex работает, а date_string.Replace("\u200e", string.Empty) символы не убирает

Comment: `"\u200e"` надо потому что, а не `@"\u200e"`. Ну ок, пусть будет так.